# Hash sum mismatch on apt update

Tags: updates, appcenter, apt

```
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                           
Err:13 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                       
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [460 kB]                                                  
Get:16 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [223 kB]
```

I'm getting this error when I run `sudo apt update`
I used to follow [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/41618) usally when I get the above error. But this time its not getting fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove ol packgae list and upgrade again, or run this shel command.

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```